# Most efficient algorithm to determine if array2 is a sub-array of array1?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

What is the most efficient algorithm to determine if array2 is a "sub-array" of array1?
(True for array1 = [9,9,10,4] and and array2 = [9, 10])

Without relying on a language-specific utility for array comparison, what's the cheapest average and worst-case solution? It seems like sorting and binary search would only get the negative case.

Comment: Must the elements of array2 be consequent? Is array3=[9,4] also a subarray of array1 or not?

Comment: The elements must be consequent. [9,4] would not be a subarray of array1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically about exact text matching algorithms, so we should at compare at least [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) string search algorithms.

Fortunately, the answer is already [on this Wikpedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), which compares the complexities (average/worst case) of several string search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply sort the two arrays and compare integer by integer. Gives a O(nlogn) solution